# Invalid LiveId: Mobile App interfacing with Microsoft LiveId (Xamarin)

Tags: c#, authentication, mobile, xamarin, windows-live-id

Hi Developers in house.

I have a mobile App with a double Authentication approach where i use Microsoft liveId.

After sometime, some users report they get "Invalid LiveID" Error even when they can manually log in to Microsoft LiveId site.

I have tried to find the cause by stepping through my codes but don't seem to understand why Microsoft returns Invalid LiveID for certain users even when they can logIn to the microsoft LiveId site and also the Mobile App previously.

Anyone ever came across this?